# Replace symbols in a string that are not letters/digits/underscore with an underscore (Javascript or Typescript)?

Tags: javascript, regex, typescript, lodash

I have a random string that comes from a data source that I do not control.
My upstream system has a requirement for such IDs: "Field names must begin with a letter and can contain only letters, digits, or underscore ('_')".

How, in Typescript/Javascript (possibly, with lodash) can I replace all string symbols that is not a letter/digit/underscore to an underscore?

Comment: Did you try writing a regex, or something with lodash? Note that this mangling may lead to collisions, as more than one input string will have the same output.

Comment: Fair point about collisions, but i do not expect these in my use case, and the risk is far from critical

Comment: You can add your specific characters link this:-
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349404/generate-random-string-characters-in-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const input = '8~3m_E!P$m%S^wx_-';
input.replace(/[\W]/gm, '_');
// output: 8_3m_E_P_m_S_wx__
```

Note: This doesn't cover this part of the requirement: 'Field names must begin with a letter'. However, because you didn't ask about it specifically, I assumed you already had it covered.